# PHP hide back end id's

Tags: php, rest, laravel-4

I'm using a REST interface to communicate between my front (Javascript application) and back end.

A standard call to my back end would be something like:

```
GET url/v1/collection/1
```

`1`in this example currently corresponds to the current unique id (pk) in my MySQL database.

This is not good practice as I understand, because I should not provide information about my back end.

What is the most common way to mask the id?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use a unique hash to every record you have.

ex:

```
id: 1
name : test
hash : UNX5K36VTRLPJZYW6VWC32L4DZGQCEI5
...
```

therefore you can also identify records by hash and retrieve their info without compromising security

Comment: Thanks, that would work as well probably. I found an alternative answer here: http://garrettstjohn.com/entry/using-uuids-laravel-eloquent-orm/

Comment: @KimGysen that's the way to go! Don't store redundant data in your database. An additional field like `hash` in this case would be such data.